# Disable timeout in javascript, where timeout already defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout

I have a timeout in javascript, which is set for every 10 seconds, this reloads the content of the page, I have been able to stop it successfully, however it will go one last time i.e. it does the timeout, i press my button to stop it, however it continues for the one last time until the 10 seconds are up.

Is there a way to cancel this preset timeout on the page so once i click the button it will stop the timeout immediately regardless of it being set for that 10 seconds.

```
loadTransferListTimer = setTimeout(function(){loadTransferList(reloadTime, txt, state);}, parseInt(reloadTime)*1000);

function enableSelect(value)
{
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax_requests/enableSelect.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {"enabled": value },
    context: document.body}).done(function() {
        if(value == "true")
        {
            window.clearTimeout('loadTransferListTimer');
            document.getElementById('enable_select').className='big-red-button';
            document.getElementById('enable_select').innerHTML='stop selected';
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.setAttribute('id', 'disable_select');
            div.setAttribute('class', 'big-red-button');
            div.innerHTML = 'Undo Selected';
            div.onclick = (function(){enableSelect("false");});
            $('.big-button-wrapper').append(div);
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('enable_select').className='big-select-button';
            document.getElementById('enable_select').innerHTML='enable select';
            $('#disable_select').remove();
            document.getElementById('enable_select').onclick = (function(){enableSelect("true");});

        }
});
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: `window.clearTimeout(loadTransferListTimer);` withotu the quotes, maybe

Comment: Many thanks, I thought it would be something silly :) removed the quotes and it now works.

Answer (score 1):

To clear it use

```
if(loadTransferListTimer )
clearTimeout(loadTransferListTimer );
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with define `loadTransferListTimer` as a `variable` and clear it without single

quote like `window.clearTimeout(loadTransferListTimer);`

```
var loadTransferListTimer = setTimeout(function(){loadTransferList(reloadTime, txt, state);}, parseInt(reloadTime)*1000);

function enableSelect(value)
{
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax_requests/enableSelect.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {"enabled": value },
    context: document.body}).done(function() {
        if(value == "true")
        {
            window.clearTimeout(loadTransferListTimer);            
            document.getElementById('enable_select').className='big-red-button';
            document.getElementById('enable_select').innerHTML='stop selected';
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.setAttribute('id', 'disable_select');
            div.setAttribute('class', 'big-red-button');
            div.innerHTML = 'Undo Selected';
            div.onclick = (function(){enableSelect("false");});
            $('.big-button-wrapper').append(div);
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('enable_select').className='big-select-button';
            document.getElementById('enable_select').innerHTML='enable select';
            $('#disable_select').remove();
            document.getElementById('enable_select').onclick = (function(){enableSelect("true");});

        }
});
```